# Java Make objects with Loop?

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to create a bunch of the same objects (Grass) with a loop in different spaces. I have a grid and I want it to fill up the entire grid with different colors. 
So I have this code so far:

```
public stage() {
    super(null);

    cast = new Cast();
    cast.setBounds(10, 10, cast.getWidth(), cast.getHeight());
    this.add(grid);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
        obj = new Object[] {
           new Grass (cast.cells[i][i])  
        };
    }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work and only makes a colored cell in the last spot of the grid. Is there anyway to make a loop for objects in every spot?

Comment: You've reassigned `obj` to a `new` array *each* time through the loop... What are you expecting to happen? Can you use an ArrayList?

Comment: Look up how Arrays (or Lists) and For loops work.

Comment: And grass is only on the main diagonal of the matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is going to create an new Object[1] 20 times.  That Array will contain an instance of Grass.  Try this instead.

```
public stage() {
    super(null);

    cast = new Cast();
    cast.setBounds(10, 10, cast.getWidth(), cast.getHeight());
    this.add(grid);

    Object obj[] = new Object[20];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
       obj[i] = new Grass (cast.cells[i][i])l
    }
}
}
```

Comment: note you have typo on 
>obj[i] = new Grass (cast.cells[i][i])l 
 There is an l in place for ;
 
 There is also an extra } at the end.

Comment: There is also the problem with the original question.  In your case the array of Grass objects goes out of scope immediately after filling it.  The array either needs to be a member variable or needs to be passed into another object to hold onto it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I realized the code I had originally put was incorrect and only would create grass diagonally. The answer you have gave worked, however what would be the best way to create the grass on the entire grid?

Comment: I have just realized what you meant by the array of Grass objects going out of scope. How would I make the array a member variable or pass into another object?